# Symfony 3 exceptions without error 500

Tags: php, symfony, exception

Is possible in symfony 3 to generate exception without internal server error?

I want do something action with this exception (add to databases) but do not stop execute application.

Comment: As long as you `catch` the exception, I don't see what the problem should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you want to do is not simply `catch` an exception, but handle (in your case: log) an *uncatched* exception.

This is a common scenario and is therefore explained [in the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html#creating-an-event-listener). Basically, you create an event listener class which you register as a service for the “kernel.event_listener” event.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this as well because I was generating custom built exceptions, but no matter what I did Symfony would return an http status of 500. I was handling errors in a controlled fashion, and just needed to notify the user, which was more of a status 200 response since it was a message to the user.

Anyways I found that this didn't work:

```
$event->setResponse(new Response(json_encode($returnArray), 200));
```

But if I added a header it works, Symfony looks for this header later and respects it. Without the header Symfony just assigns a 500 if you use an /Exception instead of an /HttpException

```
$event->setResponse(new Response(json_encode($returnArray), 200, array('X-Status-Code' => 200)));
```

I'm still new to this exception thing, so let me know if something I'm doing is wrong, but that header fixed my problems.